# Is it possible to retrieve data from the Settings App?

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10

Is it possible to access the data contained within the Battery view inside of the Settings App. More specifically, I am interested in the amount of time that has been spent on screen for each application.

[image: The Battery view within the Settings App]

Comment: Not possible. Every app is sandboxed and can't access to other apps data

Comment: Thanks @mhergon. I figured as much, however, I wanted to exhaust every avenue I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not really**, the information you want are from **Private API's** and unfortunately apple doesn't allow it.

But you can get some basic information and notifications related to battery settings like:

- > Battery State
- > Battery Percentage Level
- > Battery Monitoring - Enabled / Disabled

For more reference check this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks, @AtWork. I looked into the battery settings, however, that does not have any information for other applications, just the current application. I also received a reply from Apple stating that there is no public API to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this app as well and was wondering how it works so I downloaded the app and the Moment app actually uses as notification to prompt you to screenshot the battery life each day which I assume it then uses OCR to read the data from the screenshot.

See attached images for the detailed app flow.

[image: moment-notification][image: settings-screenshot-1]

[image: settings-screenshot-2][image: moment-usage-available]

Comment: Hi Reuben, thank you for the great input! Could you find out more about it? Does it really use OCR!?